# Dataframe sequence detection: Find groups where three rows in a row have negative values

Tags: python-3.x, database, pandas, sequence, series

Lets say I have a column `df['test']`:

`-1, -2, -3, 2, -4, 3, -5, -4, -3, -7`

So I would like to filter out the groups which have at least three negative values in a row. So

```
groups = my_grouping_function_by_sequence()
groups[0] = [-1,-2-3]
groups[1] = [-5,-4,-3,-7]
```

Are there some pre-defined checks on testing for sequences in numerical data for pandas? It does not need to be pandas, but I am searching for a fast and adaptable solution. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `GroupBy` and `cumsum` to create groups of consecutive negative numbers.

```
grps = df['test'].gt(0).cumsum()
dfs = [d.dropna() for _, d in df.mask(df['test'].gt(0)).groupby(grps) if d.shape[0] >= 3]
```

**Output**

```
for df in dfs:
    print(df)

   test
0  -1.0
1  -2.0
2  -3.0
   test
6  -5.0
7  -4.0
8  -3.0
9  -7.0
```

---

**Explanation**

Let's go through this step by step:
The first line, creates groups for consecutive negative numbers

```
print(grps)
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
9    2
Name: test, dtype: int32
```

But as we can see, it also includes the positive numbers, which we don't want to consider in our ouput. So we use `DataFrame.mask` to convert these values to `NaN`:

```
df.mask(df['test'].gt(0))
# same as df.mask(df['test'] > 0)

   test
0  -1.0
1  -2.0
2  -3.0
3   NaN
4  -4.0
5   NaN
6  -5.0
7  -4.0
8  -3.0
9  -7.0
```

Then we groupby on this dataframe and only keep the groups which are `>=` 3 rows:

```
for _, d in df.mask(df['test'].gt(0)).groupby(grps):
    if d.shape[0] >= 3:
        print(d.dropna())

   test
0  -1.0
1  -2.0
2  -3.0
   test
6  -5.0
7  -4.0
8  -3.0
9  -7.0
```

Comment: Like always - Perfect answer Erfan.

Answer (score 2):

Too acknowledge @erfan answer elegant but didn't easily understand. My attempt below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': [-1, -2, -3, 2, -4, 3, -5, -4, -3, -7]})
```

**Conditionally select rows with negatives**

```
df['j'] = np.where(df['test']<0,1,-1)
df['k']=df['j'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum()
df2=df[df['k']==3]
```

[slice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) **Iteratively the dataframe getting 3rd and 2 consecutive rows above**

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    print(df.loc[index - 2 : index + 0, 'test'])
```

Comment: I personally like this approach as well and finally used this method in my code, because it is friendly to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Erfan your answer is brilliant and I'm still trying to understand the second line. Your first line got me started to try to write it in my own, less efficient way.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': [-1, -2, -3, 2, -4, 3, -5, -4, -3, -7]})
df['+ or -'] = df['test'].gt(0)
df['group'] = df['+ or -'].cumsum()

df_gb = df.groupby('group').count().reset_index().drop('+ or -', axis=1)

df_new = pd.merge(df, df_gb, how='left', on='group').drop('+ or -', axis=1)
df_new = df_new[(df_new['test_x'] < 0) & (df_new['test_y'] >=3)].drop('test_y', 
axis=1)

for i in df_new['group'].unique():
    j = pd.DataFrame(df_new.loc[df_new['group'] == i, 'test_x'])
    print(j)
```